# Вернуь новый массив Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
[
  {
    "date": "2021-02-01",
    "retail": 115404,
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-02-02",
    "retail": 100325,
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-02-03",
    "retail": 99414,
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-02-04",
    "retail": 96167,
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-02-05",
    "retail": 94092,
  },
]
```

Подскажите как из этого вернуть новый массив `[115404,100325,99414,96167,94092]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

сложный вопрос, но попытаюсь предположить, что так:

```
const arr = arr.map(i => i.retail);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let array = [
  {
    "date": "2021-02-01",
    "retail": 115404,
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-02-02",
    "retail": 100325,
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-02-03",
    "retail": 99414,
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-02-04",
    "retail": 96167,
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-02-05",
    "retail": 94092,
  },
];

let newArray = [];

array.forEach(function(item){
  newArray.push(item.retail);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const arr= [
  {
    "date": "2021-02-01",
    "retail": 115404,
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-02-02",
    "retail": 100325,
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-02-03",
    "retail": 99414,
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-02-04",
    "retail": 96167,
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-02-05",
    "retail": 94092,
  },
];
const res = Array.from(arr, n => n.retail); 
console.log(res;)// [115404, 100325, 99414, 96167, 94092]
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]